# Python: decoding from an unknown html content

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, decode

I was trying to extract the html page using beautifulsoup in python. The page is encoded. Please find the code below.

```
try:
    f = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.#sampledomain.com')
    r1=BeautifulSoup(f).decode('ascii','ignore')
    print(r1)
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    print (e)
    print(f)
```

The output recieved is something of the form:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   ‹      Õ=isãÄ¶ŸCÿ¡Ç
  </p>
  <p>
ôÑ[Û¢£  loŒÈÓðž±ƒ~›bÇŽà)Ž qÆ8äÐ6¬    *"ûL”b›Ð©…"ñ¬i³ý† 
Ë˜•"çžÌi`…)r*¨‘¯e‘pØ~dS/UñŒÈ¥&gt;±‡š*šà]ÓƒnåpÞj8ÁAHàÁ]ÿLé¤ŸxØ%•›m+šXäÁ…
ßÔíÙ‘%b‡huµ†\üd»S7]4
›m£«›mÅ`ì^WÔ!(³böI2ö
          </ra>
         </c>
        </u>
       </d>
      </ebg>
     </e>
    </e>
   </x>
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

how do i decode this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you can't, or are unwilling to, tell us what site you're scraping then it might be easier for us to help you debug if you were to run a script that's a little more conventional and up-to-date, such as this: import requests
`import bs4

page = requests.get('http://sample.domain').content
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
print (soup)`

Comment: Then give us whatever stack dump you receive as part of your question.

Comment: That content looks zipped. Unzip it first and then soup it.